# What are the limitations of Jenkins agent none?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

### Edit

On a whim, I tried an experiment with running a simple job, and it seems environment variables can be initialized outside the scope of an agent. I'm still curious what aspects don't work with `agent none` so I'll leave the question up.

### Edit (Code)

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    
    environment {
        WORKS = 'Yes!'
    }
    
    options {
        withFolderProperties()
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('First') {
            agent any
            
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Does it work? $WORKS"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
Running on agent-5q9fg in ~/Experimental/Arbitrary Code
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'Does it work? Yes!'
Does it work? Yes!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withFolderProperties
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

### Question

So I ask StackOverflow, since there isn't a clearly listed document I could find on Jenkins, what are the limitations of the `agent none` pipeline? I specifically don't use a build agent because it is a multi-branch pipeline that targets an environment by branch name, and we sandbox production and non-production so that they cannot accidentally talk to each other. As such, the agent must be specific to the target environment.

I'd love to use a top-level `environment { ... }` directive, as well as the `options { withFolderProperties() }` configuration, but I can't be certain these will work in `agent none` scenarios.

### Background

I've been working on our internal shared library for Jenkins pipelines. I've had to make three separate PRs for the same fix because the error has been rather nebulous.

```
hudson.AbortException: Attempted to execute a step that requires a node context while ‘agent none’ was specified. Be sure to specify your own ‘node { ... }’ blocks when using ‘agent none’.
```

At first, I thought this was related to a top-level `environment { ... }` directive while leveraging `agent none`, but I still got the same error. When I moved the environment directive to each stage, I got the error again. This is because I was attempting to perform a checkout on `agent none`. I have since moved the checkout to another stage, but I got feedback asking for other considerations around how our Jenkins admins leverage the Folder Properties plugin to indicate when certain projects have been approved for a new container workflow. At first, I took the snippet they provided, but found myself using `withFolderProperties { ... }` in multiple stages. I then saw that `options { withFolderProperties() }` was a possible solution to this, but I'm back to wondering if the use of `agent none` might cause this to fail.

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
// filename:cucumberPipeline.groovy

def call(Map<String, Serializable> config) {
    String buildAgent
    String environmentName
    final String pathApi = 'src/automated-tests'
    final String pathUi = 'automated-tests'
    Map<String, String> urls

    pipeline {
        agent none

        options {
            ansiColor('xterm')
            timeout(time: 90, unit: 'MINUTES')
            timestamps()
            withFolderProperties()
        }

        stages {
            stage('Initialize Build Agent') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        buildAgent = env.V4 ? 'v4-nonprod-agent' : 'v3-nonprod-agent'
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('Switch to PRD') {
                when {
                    branch pattern: '[pP][rR][dD].*', comparator: 'REGEXP'
                }

                steps {
                    script {
                        println 'Switching to PRD build agent'
                        buildAgent = env.V4 ? 'v4-prod-agent' : 'v3-prod-agent'
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('Checkout') {
                agent { 
                    label buildAgent
                }
                steps {
                    checkout scm
                }
            }

            stage('API Tests') {
                agent { 
                    label buildAgent
                }
                environment {
                    CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_QUIET = 'true'
                }
                when {
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return fileExists(pathApi) }
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        cucumberTests(environmentName, urls, config)
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('UI Tests') {
                agent { 
                    label buildAgent
                }
                environment {
                    BROWSER = 'chrome'
                    CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_QUIET = 'true'
                    DETECT_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION = 'true'
                }
                when {
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression { return fileExists(pathUi) }
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        cucumberTests(environmentName, urls, config)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```